# Flutter: Passing a function as parameter to a Stateful Widget Class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget that returns a scaffold as follows:

```dart
class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerPage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  TimerPageState createState() => TimerPageState();
}

class TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          getMaterialTextButton('1', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed('1')),   /// ERROR
          getMaterialTextButton('2', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed2('2')),  /// ERROR
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is pass a generic function inside `getMaterialTextButton()` that will return a material button as follows:

```dart
// this function is within the TimerPageState class
Widget getMaterialTextButton(String text, String fontname, double fontsize, Function onPressAction) {
  return (
    MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onPressAction(text);
      },
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: fontname, fontSize: fontsize)
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
      shape: const CircleBorder(),
    )
  );
}

// this function is to be called when the button 1 is pressed
// also resides inside TimerPageState class
void keyPressed (String text) {
   print('Pressed: $text');
}

// this function is also to be called when button 2 is pressed
// also resides inside TimerPageState class
void keyPressed2 (String text) {
   print('Pressed: $text');
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as dart is giving me an exception:
`Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Function')`
. How can I do this operation properly?

Comment: As far as I can see, your code should not *compile*. Since it is throwing a runtime exception, I guess it did compile and the changes you made to post it here were those that broke it. Could you please post a [mcve]. That would give us a chance to check your *actual* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should prefer a full signature in your function type annotations https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-signatures-in-function-type-annotations

so

```dart
Widget getMaterialTextButton(String text, String fontname, double fontsize, Function onPressAction) {...}
```

should be

```dart
Widget getMaterialTextButton(String text, String fontname, double fontsize, void Function(String) onPressAction) {...}
```

Secondly, this is not passing in a function:

```dart
getMaterialTextButton('1', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed('1')),
```

That is calling the `keypadPressed` and passing in the result of the function, which appears to be `void`. Remove the parenthesis, and do not pass anything into `keypadPressed`, the body of `getMaterialTextButton` is where the function should be called.

```dart
getMaterialTextButton('1', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed),
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mmcdon20... I can't believe I made such a stupid boo-boo! Must be the lack of coffee causing my brain fart. I'm a newbie to flutter (only been doing it for 3 days so far).

Answer (score 1):

you are passing the return value of the function, not the function itself

change this

```
getMaterialTextButton('1', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed('1')),
```

to this

```
getMaterialTextButton('1', 'Roboto', 24, keypadPressed),
```